# Estou tentando instalar o Ionic 2 mas esta dando erro no na hora de executar o npm install -g codova ionic

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova, angular, ionic2

```
Gustavo@Gustavo-PC MINGW64 ~
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
C:\Users\Gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- cordova@6.5.0
| +-- cordova-common@2.0.0
| | +-- ansi@0.3.1
| | +-- bplist-parser@0.1.1
| | | `-- big-integer@1.6.19
| | +-- cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.15
| | +-- elementtree@0.1.7
.
.
.
  | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31
    `-- setimmediate@1.0.5

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.2 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.1

Gustavo@Gustavo-PC MINGW64 ~
$ ionic
bash: ionic: command not found

Gustavo@Gustavo-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cordova --version
bash: cordova: command not found

Gustavo@Gustavo-PC MINGW64 ~
$ ionic start like_app sidemenu --v2
bash: ionic: command not found
```

Comment: Na verdade, parece-me que o pacote foi instalado, apesar dos avisos. Veja se o caminho do `ionic` está no seu PATH

Comment: deu certo realmente esta faltando o caminho no PATH, eu tinha trocado o sistema para outro HD e acabei não vendo o caminho.

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta, e você pode marcá-la como correta. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os avisos do NPM (`WARN`) não devem impedir o funcionamento do seu pacote. Eles ocorrem quando alguma coisa *poderia* ser melhorada, ou quando algum método está deprecado, ou quando algum outro pacote é recomendado, mas, por si só, não impedem o funcionamento do mesmo. Problemas ocorrem quando você tem erros (`ERR`), e aí sim o funcionamento vai estar comprometido.

No seu caso, os avisos são sobre métodos deprecados (que eventualmente vão deixar de funcionar), dependências opcionais que não foram instaladas, e alguns *replaces* que o instalador, por algum motivo, achou que deveria fazer. Ou seja, o pacote foi instalado corretamente.

O seu problema mora no `PATH`, que é aonde você estabelece o caminho pros binários de pacotes que você quer rodar via linha de comando. No Windows 7, onde estou agora (sim, Windows 7 =/), basta apertar a tecla "Windows" e digitar "variáveis de ambiente". No primeiro resultado, um dialogo já é aberto para que você edite o `PATH`. Concatene, nessa `string`, o caminho do `ionic` (algo como `C:\user\node_modules\ionic\bin`). Depois disso, tudo deve funcionar!